# How to delete data from a file based on an offset?

Tags: c++

I am currently writing a file-page-manager program which basically write, append and read pages to binary files. For the writing function, I have to delete the whole content of the specified page and write new content. I need to delete data from a file within a specific range like delete data from position 30 to position 4096.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no more data after position 4096 then you can use [truncate(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/truncate64.2.html) to shrink the file to 30 bytes.

If you have more data after 4096 byte then you could first overwrite the data starting at position 30 by the data present after 4096th byte.  Then you can truncate the file to [original_filesize - (4096-30)] bytes.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to delete data in a file is to mark it as deleted. Use some value to indicate that the section(s) are deleted. Otherwise, copy the sections you want to save to a new file.

Comment: what kind of character can I use to denote a character has been deleted or from this point there is no more data to read?

Answer (score 0):

So easy with `std::string`

Follow the steps:
**read the file and extract it to the std::string**

```
std::ifstream input_file_stream( "file" );
const unsigned size_of_file = input_file_stream.seekg( 0, std::ios_base::end ).tellg();

input_file_stream.seekg( 0, std::ios_base::beg ); // rewind

std::string whole_file( size_of_file, ' ' );        // reserved space for the whole file

input_file_stream.read( &* whole_file.begin(), size_of_file );
```

**then erase what you want:**

```
// delete with offset
whole_file.erase( 10,       // size_type index
                 200 );      // size_type count
```

**and finally write to a new file:**

```
// write it to the new file:
std::ofstream output_file_stream( "new_file" );
output_file_stream.write( &*whole_file.begin(), whole_file.size() );
output_file_stream.close();

input_file_stream.close();
```